# Save Windows Form App Combobox and Textbox Selections of Individual Users and Load Them With a Button

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a windows form application written in c#. It has a textbox, a combobox, and a button. The button is a save button and is intended to save the values the user has put in the textbox and set the combobox to when clicked, and should be able to save multiple different selections, such as one user adding “test1” to the textbox and selecting the 0 index option of the combobox and clicks the save button to save those options, and then another user can adding “test2” to the textbox and selecting the 2 index option of the combobox and clicks the save button to save those options, resulting in two separate saved selections that can be loaded back into the application, resulting in the form having the save file data selected.

The issue is I have no idea how to implement a function like this, or where to begin. I’ve looked into saving the options of a user as an xml file, but apparently this can’t be done with combobox data.

Here's a diagram of what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Any suggestions on how this could be implemented in a Visual Studio Windows Form Application in c#, or where one would begin?

Comment: You can start here: https://www.guru99.com/c-windows-forms-application.html

Comment: Thanks, but I solved it. Will explain how later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This described function can be achieved using txt files. I used them since they're fairly simple.

To save:

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
   sfd.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
   sfd.ShowDialog();
   string name = sfd.Title; 
   string filePath = sfd.FileName; 

   StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath);
   // Write the text you want to the file.
   sw.WriteLine(MyTextBox.Text);
   sw.WriteLine(MyComboBox.SelectedIndex); 
   // You could do MyComboBox.SelectedItem if you evaluate what index the item 
   // belongs at when reading back the file for the load function.

   sw.Close();

}
```

To load:

```
private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
   ofd.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
   ofd.ShowDialog();

   // If the user doesn't select a file, cancels, or exists the dialogue box 
   nothing is done.
   if (ofd.FileName == null || ofd.FileName.Equals("")) { }

   // Else if the user has selected a file, the file's text is converted when necessary, and used to change the value of the applications controls.
   else
   {
       // Get the contense of the txt file as a string array.
       string[] list = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);

       // Reads the text stored in the txt file and puts it as the value for the boxes.
       MyTextBox.Text = list[0];
       MyComboBox.SelectedIndex = list[1];

   }
```

}